# Can Mathematica be configured to not lazy-evaluate by default?

Tags: evaluation, testing-and-verification

I notice that `VerificationTest` will see `False` for a function in cell 1

```
f[x_] :=(x - 1) (x - 3) / (x + 2)
```

referred to in cell 2:

```
VerificationTest[Limit[f[x], Rule[x, -2]], \[Infinity]]
```

after hitting **Shift+Enter** in cell 2 only (in a newly-opened notebook with many, many cells) —but **Evaluation > Evaluate Notebook** will cause  `VerificationTest` to see `True`. Is there some default option or something I am missing here or is this just the way it is for now?

Comment: You presumably intend your function to be `f[x_] := (x - 1) (x - 3)/(x + 2)` since you expect a pole at `x == 2`. Your `Limit` is written improperly using `RightArrow[x, -2]` rather than `Rule[x, -2]` See documentation for [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html) The `Limit` should not successfully evaluate no matter how you initiate the evaluation.

Comment: @bob-hanlon your presumption is correct. I have updated my question. Once I get back to my Mathematica machine, I will verify my `Limit` syntax. Why would an error not be thrown?

Comment: The `VerificationTest` outcome is `Failure` this presumably covers all errors. If you extract the `Limit` and evaluate it separately, it returns the error message "Limit::lim: Limit specification x\[RightArrow]-2 is not of the form x -> x0." and returns the `Limit` unevaluated.

Comment: So what you are saying is that you wrote down the definition of `f`, *didn't evaluate it* (so `f` remained undefined), and only ran the verification test?

Comment: @rahul I am saying that `f` is defined in a different cell (in a notebook full of cells) from the cell with the test in it. I see now that cells are lazy loaded: i need to *Shift+Enter* on the `f` cell as well as the test cell ---this answers my question part but does not answer the possibility that Mathematica can be configured to behave differently...

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you give detailed, step-by-step instructions to reproduce the problem?  I cannot reproduce it.

Comment: Note that Mathematica is not source-file focused like many other languages, e.g. Python.  In Python you don't compile like in C, but the typical workflow is still to 1. write program 2. run program 3. update program 4. re-run program.  Mathematica is meant to be used interactively, and a notebook is not a "source file".  Both the language itself and the notebook interface are optimized for interactive use. Trying to use source files is in my opinion counterproductive.  Give the interactive workflow a try.

Answer (score 1):

I think you improperly copied your function

- You wrote: `f[x_] :=(x - 1) (x - 3) / x + 2`
- I think you meant to write: `f[x_] :=(x - 1) (x - 3) / (x + 2)`

When you define you function in the latter form, this is what the code yields when you click Shift+Enter:
[image]

Comment: Your correction is correct but did you just enter the correct function and hit `Shift+Enter` or did you have to Evaluate Notebook? (What I entered in my question is NOT what I entered in Mathematica...)

Comment: I simply hit Shift+Enter and it worked.

Comment: @jake_feuerman from your screenshot above, I am very certain that should you _not_ enter (hit *Shift+Enter*) cell 3 (which can happen quite naturally after opening a closed notebook) but hit *Shift+Enter* for cell 4 you will get the behavior described in my question. It would be a bit tragic when the moderators fail to perform this simple test.